# Entity Framework Pagination (Select records using string datetime column)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, pagination, linq-to-entities

I have a table which has startdate (in format "yyyymmddhhss")and the corresponding entity attribute is string type. I would like to use LINQ To SQL get all the records with StartDate >= SelectedStartDate. Since this table has more than 10 million records, I need to use pagination as well.

Could anyone please suggest on how to implement this/

Regards,

Raaj

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be of course to migrate the string values to a `DATETIME` column and query the data from that column.

But if you don't have enough privileges to do that, you're lucky you have the format `yyyymmddhhss` in your table because that preserves the natural order of dates; all you have to do is to convert the parameter to a string in the required format:

```
public IEnumerable<YourDataObject> GetData(DateTime date, PageInfo pageInfo)
{
    var startDate = date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHss");
    return _dbContext.Table
        .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
        .Where(x => String.Compare(x.StartDate, startDate) >= 1)
        .Skip(pageInfo.PageSize * pageInfo.PageIndex)
        .Take(pageInfo.PageSize)
        .Select(x => new YourDataObject
        {
            //
        });
}
```

Here is a sample output in LINQPad:

[image: Sample output.]

Comment: But this table's column type is varchar. Sorry I forgot to mention this.

Comment: @Raajkumar this seems to work as long as your input date `SelectedStartDate` is a DateTime. If it's a string in the format you said, then you can modify the method just a little, `startDate` then just need to set directly to the input string date. If the input string date has different format, then you need to parse for a DateTime first and set `startDate` to a string as in the method written here.

Comment: In .Where(x => x.StartDate >= startDate) , x.StartDate is string. How can we use >= operand ? We cannot use DateTime.Parse() method inside the Where().

Comment: @Raajkumar, please see the edit. Instead of `>=` operator I should have wrote `String.Compare`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel sorry for myself as I didn't paid attention to the API's.